# How to populate comboBox

Tags: java, javafx

I have an FXML file which have a combo box which i want to populate in *initialize()* method in controller

Controller class:

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> comboBox;

void initialize()
{
    comboBox.addItem("123");
}
```

Whenever i want to complie i've got an error:

```
"The method addItem(String) is undefined for the type ComboBox<String>"
```

After reading lecture from oracle i've got the information, that combo box works for Objects, which String is, isnt it ?

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `setItems(ObservableList<T>)`.

`addItem` isn't a method declared for `ComboBox`. Check out the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#setItems-javafx.collections.ObservableList-).

You can add items by creating an observable list, then passing it to `setItems`:

```
comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("123"))
```

Or you can pass the `ComboBox` the list of items via it's constructor.